# Vue, изменение $root.$data через функцию без использования Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет, делаю отображение контента в зависимости от авторизации на своём учебном проекте на Vue. 
Для авторизации использую Firebase. 
До этого объявлял переменную isAutorized в $root.$data, но тогда любой может из VueDevTools изменить переменную и просто отобразить весь контент, который только для авторизованных, поэтому сделал проверку через функцию, но тогда при обновлении страницы v-if="!$root.currentUser" не обрабатывается и отображается неправильный контент, хотя пользователь авторизован. 

Можно как-нибудь объявить переменную в data в $root, но чтобы её не могли изменять из VueDevTools, то есть она должна быть закрыта и изменяться через функции, как во Vuex, при том чтобы v-if срабатывало ? 

Спасибо.

Вот код:

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  methods: {
    currentUser: function() {
      return auth.currentUser
    }
  },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<div class="navigation__enter">
  <span class="navigation__register" v-if="!$root.currentUser()" data-text='Регистрация' @click="registerModalOpen"></span>
  <span class="navigation__exit" v-else="!$root.currentUser()" data-text='Выйти' @click="logoutUser"></span>
  <span class="navigation__login" v-if="!$root.currentUser()" data-text='Вход' @click="loginModalOpen"></span>
  <span class="navigation__login navigation__login_user" v-else data-text='Профиль'></span>
</div>
```

auth.currentUser принимает текущего авторизованного пользователя.

Comment: в продакшен режиме VueDevTools  - не доступен

Comment: А из за чего при обновлении страницы в v-else не заходит, хотя условия выполняется, с чем это связано?

Comment: сложно сказать, но могу сказать, что 2 разных `v-if...v-else` не должны идти подряд. Их надо обернуть в тег `template`, либо любой другой

Comment: `v-else="!$root.currentUser()"` - разве эта директива принимает параметр (значение)? Имхо, в этом и заключается ошибка, из-за которой логика шаблона работает "неправильно".